# Installing rpm and yum in anaconda python on centos 7

Tags: python, anaconda, centos7

How do I install the redhat yum packages within an anaconda environment on CentOS? These packages exist in the standard Centos dist:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rpm
>>> import yum 
>>> print(rpm.__package__, rpm.__file__, rpm.__path__,rpm.__version__)
('rpm', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/__init__.pyc', ['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm'], '4.11.3')
>>> print(yum.__package__, yum.__file__, yum.__path__,yum.__version__)
('yum', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.pyc', ['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum'], '3.4.3')
```

I can't find similar packages (in the ways that I know) for anaconda:

```
$ source anaconda3/bin/activate python2.7  
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org 
>>> import rpm;
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rpm
>>> import yum  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yum
>>>
```

pip and conda search don't seem to have these packages either.

Answer (score 0):

When you run source 
    anaconda3/bin/activate python2.7 
you are running python2.7 using a different virtual environment, where the package repository is different. You should source into the venv and install the packages there.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that. But I don't understand where to find the package except from a .rpm file. And I don't understand how to install that into the anaconda environment.

Comment: That depends on how the virtualenv was created. Some of the options allows you to copy the system packages, but if rpm was installed after the venv creation, it is not sync later on.